# How to change schema name on runtime for EntityManager

Tags: entity-framework-6, devforce

Our application connects to oracle.
It should change schema name on runtime, otherwise it causes exception to connect to different schema.
Current solution is to remove `Schema="XXX"` in edmx file before release.
Do you have any better idea?

Answer (score 1):

DevForce itself doesn't provide anything to change the schema at runtime.  You might be able to implement an EF [IDbConnectionInterceptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.interception.idbconnectioninterceptor(v=vs.113).aspx) to do this, although I haven't tried.  Take a look at the docs for this interface, as well as some older tricks others have used with EF to change the Oracle schema at runtime.